# What does “mov [edi+68h], eax” mean?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, winapi

What does **mov     [edi+68h], eax** mean in the following asm code

```
.text:0083FB35       call    esi ; RegisterWindowMessageW
.text:0083FB37       push    offset My_Priv8_Msg ; "MY_PRIVATE_MSG"
.text:0083FB3C       mov     [edi+68h], eax
```

Comment: It moves the result of the `RegisterWindowMessageW` function, that is returned in `eax`, to a memory location. Probably a structure member with `edi` being a pointer to the structure and `0x68` the offset of the structure member within the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the call to the RegisterWindoMessageW is stored in eax. esi is a pointer and the code is saving the result of the function call to the address pointed to by esi plus offset 68h.